# Как вывести model в каждом HTML шаблоне?

Tags: python, html, django

Я вывожу модель `Categorie` в `header` своего шаблона.
Но создавать запрос в каждой функций внутри views.py я не хочу.

Можно ли как-то вывести модель в каждом шаблоне зaдaвая только один запрос?

Я попробовал использовать `templatetags`, но что так:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_categories(context):
    return Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

что вот так

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_categories(context):
    categories = Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')
    args = {}
    
    for cat in categories:
        args[cat.text] = {
        'id':cat.id,
        }
        if cat.parent:
            args[cat.text]['parent_id'] = cat.parent.id
            args[cat.text]['parent_text'] = cat.parent.text
    return args
```

Ничего не работает правильно:

```
{% for cat in header_categories %}
    cat.text
{% endfor %}
```

Я пытался через JS:

```
 var arr = {%header_categories%}
```

Но Django все  коверкает:

```
 {&#x27;Женская одежда&#x27;: {&#x27;id&#x27;: 19},
```

Answer (score 0):

**tags.py**

```
from django import template
from apps.models import Categorie

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('apps/tags.html')
def header_categories():
    categories = Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')
    args = {}    
    for cat in categories:
        args[cat.text] = {
        'id':cat.id,
        }
        if cat.parent:
            args[cat.text]['parent_id'] = cat.parent.id
            args[cat.text]['parent_text'] = cat.parent.text
    return args
```

**tags.html**

```
{% for cat in page_obj %}
    {{ cat.parent_id }}:{{ cat.parent_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load tags %}
{% header_categories %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо исправить ваш код в шаблоне, вы скобочки пропустили в цикле:

```
{% for cat in header_categories %}
    {{ cat.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Ссылка на оф. документацию по шаблонам в django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Работать будет только при условии, что `header_categories` будет содержать список объектов у которых есть параметр `text`.